# my mpi program behaves randomly

Tags: multithreading, mpi

I have an mpi program that behaves randomly, sometimes finishes normally and others it hangs out, i create an additional thread in every process. I've no clue of what can be happening.
Here is an abstract of the code:

```
void* listen(void * args) {
    int id = ((__arg *) (args))->id;
    while (true) {
        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Recv(&sender, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 10000 + id, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        if (sender >= 90000) {
                    // ...
        } else {
            MPI_Recv(&node, 1, MPI_INT, sender, 30000 + id, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            int n = 3;//change later
            MPI_Send(&n, 1, MPI_INT, sender, 20000 + sender, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    pthread_t tid;
    __arg args;
    args.id = rank;
    args.np = size;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &listen, (void *) (&args));

    for (int s_aux = 0; s_aux < local_vertex_count; ++s_aux) {
        int s = size * s_aux + rank;
        queue<int> Q;
        Q.push(s);
        while (!Q.empty()) {
            int v = Q.front();
            Q.pop();
            int own = v % size; 
            int idxv = v / size; 
            if (own == rank) {
                //...
            } 
            else {// send message to owner
                MPI_Send(&rank, 1, MPI_INT, own, 10000 + own, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&v, 1, MPI_INT, own, 30000 + own, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                int neighbors;
                MPI_Status status;
                MPI_Recv(&neighbors, 1, MPI_INT, own, 20000 + rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            }//send message to owner
        }// while (!Q.epmty())
    }

    //tell all processes to finish
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int buf = 90000 + rank;
        MPI_Send((void*) &buf, 1, MPI_INT, i, 10000 + i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not all to easy to follow, could you maybe make it simpler or explain in words, what it's supposed to do? what's `s`, that you push to the queue? Also, I only see one push per queue...

Comment: what i am trying to do is a BFS, `s` is the global vertex index. I load the graph such that process i has the vertices k*size+i (size is the number of processes). In BFS we have to push all the neighbors of the current vertex, if the current vertex is not owned by the current process, i ask the correct process to send this vertex' neighbors. I create a thread within each MPI process to answer to other processes' requests. I don't know if the problem comes from mixing threads with MPI.

Comment: My first guess would be unmatched Messages. Or maybe, a queue runs out of elements and later gets new elements (from another process). These will not be processed since the loop `while (!Q.empty())` already terminated.

Comment: It looks like you are using blocking send receives between neighbors, but that there isn't explicit sequencing to the send/receive order.  If they are not sending/receiving in a specific order, you can get caught in locks where all tasks are receiving, and none are responding.

For something like this, you should probably order your communications, or look into non-blocking send/receives.  Otherwise, a Parallel Debugger (Totalview or something) might come in handy at this point)

Comment: I've found that this line `MPI_Recv(&neighbors, 1, MPI_INT, own, 20000 + rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);` is the one with the problem, if I comment it, it works fine, but still, i can't figure out what's the problem with that Recv